# How to insert a keyword after 3 CONSECUTIVE pattern using SED

Tags: sed

The below example gives the required result but it works for consecutive and non-consecutive pattern search

I need to have this logic only for consecutive patterns

ORANGE should be inserted after every 3 continuous occurrences of APPLE

```
sed "/APPLE/{p;s/.*/1/;H;g;/^\(\n1\)\{3\}$/s//ORANGES/p;d}" < input.txt > output.txt
```

Input

```
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
MANGO
APPLE
APPLE
```

CURRENT OUTPUT

```
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
ORANGE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
ORANGE
APPLE
APPLE
MANGO
APPLE
ORANGE -------->>> NOT NEEDED <<
APPLE
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts, please do add sample of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Does it __have to__ be `sed`? Why not use another, way simpler tool? If by it, why not python or perl or ruby?

Comment: `/^\(\n1\)\{3\}$` Why are you checking if there are 3 ones?

Comment: @KamilCuk, thanks for your answer, here the requirement is restricted to be used only with shell scripting and not PERL or ruby. Is it possible to edit/ modify the below script to meet the requirement 
sed "/APPLE/{p;s/.*/1/;H;g;/^\(\n1\)\{3\}$/s//ORANGES/p;d}" < input.txt > output.txt

Comment: `with shell scripting` But sed is not shell scripting. Sed is an external program, like perl and ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/APPLE/!b;n;//!b;n;//!b;a\ORANGE' file
```

This will append the line `ORANGE` after 3 consecutive lines with the string `APPLE` contained with them.

To parametrize the above solution for n consecutive lines (e.g. 5), use:

```
sed '/APPLE/!b;'$(printf 'n;//!b;%.0s' {2..5})'a\ORANGE' file
```

Another alternative:

```
sed '/APPLE/!b;:a;N;/\n[^\n]*APPLE[^\n]*$/!b;s/[^\n]*/&/3;Ta;a\ORANGE' file
```

If the value to be appended is a variable, use:

```
sed '/APPLE/!b;:a;N;/\n[^\n]*APPLE[^\n]*$/!b;s/[^\n]*/&/3;Ta;a\'"$var" file
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @potong, i would appreciate if you can explain to me the working of this script , especially the purpose of {2..5} used

Comment: @Ankur The first solution for 3 consecutive lines, hardcodes this `n;//!b` pattern two times into the solution. The second solution, programs this hardcode into the sed program using the interpolation of the `$(...)` whiich runs the code within and substitutes it into the sed program. `printf` will print `n;//!b` four times if it has four parameters. `{2..5}` converts to `2 3 4 5` and the `%.0s` template accepts these arguments (zero width). Thus the code `printf 'n;//!b;%.0s' {2..5}` converts to `n;//!b;n;//!b;n;//!b;n;//!b;`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @potong , your alternate script worked the way I needed..but there is one small thing that is still missing and i am not sure why is that happening...

In the actual scenario, i am trying to access the pattern value (in this example orange) through a variable
like below 
====
pattern = ORANGE
 sed '/APPLE/!b;:a;N;/\n[^\n]*APPLE[^\n]*$/!b;s/[^\n]*/&/3;Ta;a\${pattern}'
===
But in spite of printing ORANGE it is printing {pattern} in the output

Comment: @Ankur The sed program is surrounded by single quotes, this will not interpolate the shell variable.To allow this just surround the variable by single quotes. However, since the variable is the last part of the program just remove the last single quote and insert it before the variable. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

> ORANGE should be inserted after every 3 continuous occurrences of APPLE

The following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF |
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
MANGO
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
EOF
sed '
# Add to hold space and inspect hold space
H
x
/^\(\nAPPLE\)\{3\}$/{
    # 3 apples in hold space, means we add orange to pattern space
    # and clear hold space
    s///
    x
    s/$/\nORANGE/
    x   
}
# There are at least 3 lines in hold space
/^\(\n[^\n]*\)\{3\}/{
    # Remove first line from hold space
    s/\n[^\n]*//
}
x
'
```

outputs:

```
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
ORANGE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
ORANGE
APPLE
APPLE
MANGO
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
ORANGE
```